# What's the admission criteria of a mathematics master program (especially in Europe)?

Tags: graduate-admissions, mathematics, masters, united-kingdom, finland

My question is about the admission criteria of a mathematics master program. I am at my final year of undergraduate study, and I am going to apply to a mathematics master program (especially in UK and Finland).

To be more specific, I wanna apply to UK. As far as I know, UK universities' mathematics program is usually 12 months. Since I wanna continue the PhD after the master, will this program suit me? And about the Finland, there is no detailed core courses requirements on the website, so I wanna know the specific requirements.

Edit: If I hold a UK mathematics master degree, can I continue my PhD degree in UK or other Europe countries? In my impression, if I want to apply for a position of PhD, I have to prepare a year earlier. But if I study in UK, I will not have that time to prepare. Is that right?

Comment: I suggest asking the question about UK master degree and what it qualifies you for as a different question.

Comment: @TommiBrander Thanks for your suggestion, I will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general information on the master's admissions in Finland, see the Study in Finland website: http://www.studyinfinland.fi/how_to_apply/masters_admissions

For particular programmes, you'll have to check the website of the university and try to find the relevant information there. Here is an example from University of Jyväskylä: https://www.jyu.fi/en/apply/masters-programmes/masters-degree-programmes/mathematics/admission-criteria

The basic requirements seem to be an English proficiency and bachelor-equivalent degree in a related field. Since the programmes in different countries vary widely, applicants will be judged individually, so it is impossible to comment on the meaning of having or not having taken certain courses, especially since "geometry" might mean Euclidean geometry or differential geometry, and you might be applying for a program with a focus on differential geometry or something else.

If you are a good student and someone at your faculty has connections to mathematicians in Finland, do ask for them to write a letter of reference and otherwise let the people at the target university know that you are applying.

Relevant keywords in Finnish:

- maisteri (master)
- maisteriohjelma (master programme)
- maisteriopinnot (master studies)
- pääsyvaatimukset (admission criteria)
- matematiikka (mathematics)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sadly, my university does not have the connection with Europe universities, should I directly write a letter to the professor in Finland to state my study case?

Comment: For PhD studies that answer would be yes. For master studies I cannot really say, but I would suggest more on writing a good motivational letter or such, if such is asked for. It should cover most of the same ground.